# Is it possible to put the results of these for loops into one line?

Tags: python, histogram

I'm trying to create a vertical histogram that takes user input and displays the results in a vertical histogram.

I think I've figured out how to do it using for loops and f string format, but I don't know how, or if it's even possible, to get the outcomes on the same line so that it prints on one row.

Here is my code below:

```
def vert_histogram():
        print('----------------------------------------------------------------------')
        print('Vertical Histogram')

        choices = 'Progress | Trailer | Retriever| Exclude'
        print(choices)

        star = '*'
        no_star = ' '
        

        for i in range(progress):
            print(f'{star:>4}')

        for i in range(trailer):
            print(f'{star:>15}')

        for i in range(retriever):
            print(f'{star:>26}')

        for i in range(exclude):
            print(f'{star:>36}')
                   
       
            
vert_histogram()
```

At the moment, my current output looks like this:

```
 Vertical Histogram 
 Progress | Trailer | Retriever| Exclude
    *
    *
    *
    *
               *
               *
                          *
                          *
                          *
                                   *
```

Comment: Is there a reason you do not just use matplotlib?

Comment: Can you show what you want the output to look like. Do you want all the stars on one line?

Comment: you need a double for loop over row and then sample columns if you need to print a star, write a function that returns a space or star depending on the row

Comment: see if my response addresses your problem. You don't need 4 for loops to get this done.

Comment: @angrymantis, I'm not familiar with matplotlib and I want to do this using basic operations

Comment: Thanks, @JoeFerndz, I'll check it out

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

```
progress = 4
trailer = 2
retriever = 3
exclude = 1

stars = [progress,trailer,retriever,exclude]
maxval = max(stars)

print('----------------------------------------------------------------------')
print('Vertical Histogram')

choices = 'Progress | Trailer | Retriever | Exclude'
print(choices)
for i in range (maxval):
    a = ['*' if i < star else ' ' for star in stars]
    print (f'{a[0]:>4}{a[1]:>11}{a[2]:>11}{a[3]:>11}')
```

This will result in the following output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Vertical Histogram
Progress | Trailer | Retriever | Exclude
   *          *          *          *
   *          *          *           
   *                     *           
   *
```